# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Events' object has no attribute 'get_channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make it so that when my bot starts, it sends messages to certain chats. With normal power-up, everything is fine, and when I already use a special restart command, this error is issued. Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    changeStatus.start()
    kvuqqs = client.get_channel(906998823187017728)
    librar = client.get_channel(906168716197232660)

    await kvuqqs.send('Айоу! Бот был включен. \nК сожалению, на данный момент обновлений нет. \n`l.хелп`')
    await librar.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Бот был включен!', description='Версия бота на данный момент: 2.0.1.', color=random.choice(colors)))
```

And also a full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Events' object has no attribute 'get_channel'
```

Answer (score 0):

bruh
to get a channel from id you need a guild

**example :-**

```
guild = client.get_guild(ID)
channel = guild.get_channel(ID)
```

and

Getting a channel or guild by id is privileged intent

Add this code in your bot (if you haven't)

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='prefix', intents=intents)
```

You have to turn these intents on in [Discord Dev Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

You can read more about intents here :- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html